# Rails how to get the top 4 values of each ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table which store each type of clothes we sale, a simplification could be :

```
TypeCloth (id, name_type, desc)
```

I have a second table storing all articles for each type of cloths

```
Cloth (id, name_cloth, desc, price, ... , type_cloth_id)
```

I want to do a query that let me show a quick view of the last 4 cloths of each type of cloths

I've done something like this :

```
@type_cloths = TypeCloth.all
@cloth = Cloth.where(type_cloth_id: @type_cloths.ids)
```

If I put a LIMIT 4 here I will just get 4 cloths. I would like to get 4 cloths of each types

I'm sure i'm missing something obvious here

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQLite3 with ActiveRecord

Comment: If your collection is not so large, you can `Cloth.all.group_by(&:type_cloth_id).flat_map { _2.last(4) }`

Comment: Which sqlite3 version @Tikroz?

Comment: 3.34.1 2021-01-20

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can use [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

In your `Cloth` model you can define such scope

```rb
scope :first_each_type, ->(count) do
  ranked_clothes =
    select(
      "clothes.*",
      "dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY clothes.type_cloth_id ORDER BY clothes.id DESC) rank"
    )

  from("(#{ranked_clothes.to_sql}) AS clothes").where("rank <= ?", count)
end
```

And than call it as

```rb
Cloth.first_each_type(4)
```

If you need to return first N clothes by specified type, you can use something like this

```rb
scope :first_each_type, ->(count, type_cloth_ids = nil) do
  ranked_clothes =
    select(
      "clothes.*",
      "dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY clothes.type_cloth_id ORDER BY clothes.id DESC) rank"
    )

  ranked_clothes = ranked_clothes.where(type_cloth_id: type_cloth_ids) if type_cloth_ids

  from("(#{ranked_clothes.to_sql}) AS clothes").where("rank <= ?", count)
end
```

And than

```rb
Cloth.first_each_type(4)
Cloth.first_each_type(4, [1, 2])
```

If your collection is not so large, you can

```rb
Cloth.all.group_by(&:type_cloth_id).flat_map { _2.last(4) }
```

(SQLite has cluster index and you don't need to order records)

Comment: Thanks but I'm using SQLite3 is there any equivalence ?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite3 has support for window functions since version 3.25.0, so you could use ROW_NUMBER() for that;

```
Cloth
  .from(
    TypeCloth
      .joins(:cloths)
      .where(id: @type_cloths.ids)
      .select(
        'cloths.id',
        'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cloths.type_cloth_id) AS rn'
      ),
    :c
  )
  .joins('JOIN cloths on cloths.id = c.id')
  .where('rn <= 4');
```

You have to join cloths again with the subquery in `from` which is odd, but it's the Active Record way of using `from`. Or you could write it as a "raw" SQL query.